# How can you "center crop" a Widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a [VideoPlayer](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/video_player) widget that needs to be fullscreen and also fit the aspect ratio of the source video. In order to achieve that, I'll need to chop off either the top/bottom or the left/right of the video.

I had hoped the following might achieve this, but I think I must be using `FittedBox` incorrectly as it causes my `VideoPlayer` to disappear:

```dart
final Size size = controller.value.size;
return new FittedBox(
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  child: new AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: size.width / size.height,
    child: new VideoPlayer(controller)
  ),
);
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Have you tried using ClipRect? https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ClipRect-class.html

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Finally solved it. There were a few missing pieces:

1. I needed an `OverflowBox` with no restrictions so that my child could grow as large as needed.
2. I needed the child of `FittedBox` to actually enforce a size to stop the layout system from crashing.
3. Now that my widget will paint outside of its bounds, we also want to put a `ClipRect` in there to stop this from happening.

```dart
final Size size = controller.value.size;
return new ClipRect(
  child: new OverflowBox(
    maxWidth: double.infinity,
    maxHeight: double.infinity,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: new FittedBox(
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: new Container(
        width: size.width,
        height: size.height,
        child: new VideoPlayer(controller)
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Superb solution. Instead of using a package, this solves the very issue of cropping anywhere you want.

Comment: Any idea how to crop at an arbitrary offset?

Answer (score 5):

Starting with the above solution I came up with this:

```
final Size size = _controller.value.size;
return Container(
  color: Colors.lightBlue,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child: FittedBox(
           alignment: Alignment.center,
       fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
       child: Container(
         width: size.width,
         height: size.height,
         child: VideoPlayer(_controller))),
      ),
)
```

The inner `Container` provides the size for the `Texture` inside the `VideoPlayer`.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old, but imma post it here so if others find it they find another solution. So basically, if you always want a picture to cover an area, but wanna always show the middle of the picture (center crop i guess) create a sizedbox around the image. You may say it is not responsive or has to be hardcoded. Just calculate it from something. I did like that:

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)=>SizedBox(child: Image.asset("home.jpg",fit: BoxFit.cover,),width: isWide ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-350 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,);
}
```

Here, i even check the "resolution of the device". isWide boolean is true, if MediaQuery.orientation == landscape. If so, i have a 350px menu on the left side, so i can calculate the remaining space for the sizedbox.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problems with this, and the accepted answer didn't solve it for me. I was just trying to get a background image to fit vertically and overflow horizontally. Here's how I ended up doing it:

```
OverflowBox(
    maxWidth: double.infinity,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child:
        Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: [
            UnconstrainedBox(
                constrainedAxis: Axis.vertical,
                child: Image.asset('images/menu_photo_1.jpg', fit: BoxFit.cover))
        ])
)
```

Comment: Doesn't the Image widget have box fitting built in? https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html

Comment: It does - and as you can see in my code, I'm using it too. It just didn't seem to do the job.