# Flutter VideoPlayer - Cover / Center Crop inside a Widget ( Not Screen )

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a list view with widgets. I would like to add video players inside those widgets but it should be cover or center crop.

Any solution or suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm already learning and working on it. I don't think you understand issue and complexity here. This type of general answer doesn't make any sense. I'm talking about center-crop scaling ( not an image ). I'll wait for answer from people who have actually worked on those. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49482297/how-can-you-center-crop-a-widget-in-flutter/49523770

Comment: Thanks. Actually that  solution doesn't work for VideoPlayer. It does center crop inside a widget but uses aspect ratio of the screen where it should uses aspect ratio of the widget . We can't access height / width of the widget directly - so there is complexity there. I'm just trying to find out if there is any easy solution before I come up with a complex solution.

Comment: Try asking flutter's official discord group. I think they know the answer.

Comment: @SafiulAzam did you ever found a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've figured out so far :

```
          AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 1,
            child: ClipRRect(
              child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
                child: Center(
                  child: VideoPlayer(_videoPlayerController),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```