# Flutter: video player crop/cover

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

I'm trying to show a video inside a container, videos could exceed container's aspect ratio, so the they need to be cropped.

With images it is simple as that:

```
Image.network(someUrl, fit: BoxFit.cover)
```

but how to do it with `VideoPlayer`?

my current code looks like this:

```
Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: double.infinity,
                child: ShowcaseVideoPlayer(someUrl)
              ),
              Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
              ),
            ],);

class ShowcaseVideoPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;

  ShowcaseVideoPlayer(this.url);

  @override
  _ShowcaseVideoPlayerState createState() => _ShowcaseVideoPlayerState();
}

class _ShowcaseVideoPlayerState extends State<ShowcaseVideoPlayer> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.url);

    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();
    _controller.setVolume(0);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          _controller.play();
          // If the VideoPlayerController has finished initialization, use
          // the data it provides to limit the aspect ratio of the VideoPlayer.
          return AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
            // Use the VideoPlayer widget to display the video.
            child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
          );
        } else {
          // If the VideoPlayerController is still initializing, show a
          // loading spinner.
          return Center(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

I need a stack as I will have to show other things over the video. I tried without the stack and the player maintains the aspect ratio of the video, basically letter-boxing it. With the stack, the video stratches, losing the original aspect ratio:

[image]

to be clear, what I want is this:

[image]

EDIT: I tried random things on it and managed to achieve something, I removed the `Container` and wrapped the `VideoPlayer` like this:

```
Stack(
            children: [
              OverflowBox(
                      child: Wrap(
                          children: [
                            ShowcaseVideoPlayer(someUrl)
                          ],
                      ),
                    )]);
```

now the the video is actually cropped, but not centered (I see the upper part of the video instead of the central one). Wrapping `Wrap` in a `Center` and setting `alignment: Alignment.center` on `OverfowBox` have no effect. Any idea?

Comment: did you manage to achieve this?

Comment: @user12051965 unfortunately not, we settled for resizing the widget.

Comment: check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49482297/how-can-you-center-crop-a-widget-in-flutter). I think it solve your issue